# where put db connection function in a web page

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a newbie in php programming and I'd construct a php site with mysql db. Now I don't know where often a web programmer insert db connection function in his web page.

Comment: the question is subjective, any answer could deserve a merit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separate the connection and the connectionsettings into e.g. `connect.inc.php` and `config.inc.php`

Store the settings in config.inc.php and call that file (`require_once()`) from connect.inc.php. Then call connect.inc.php from the page you are working on (e.g. index.php)

Answer (score 1):

That very much depends on the situation.

A small system might simply use a `require("db_connection_script.inc.php")` to load the database connection information and then run queries with that from then on. This has the advantage of simplicity but does leave the connection open a lot longer than necessary. Also, be sure that if someone runs `db_connection_script.inc.php` on its own they don't get access to any kind of information you don't want to give out!

It sounds like the above is the best choice in your case, but I'll include some other examples of usage for completeness.

If you were looking to create a larger, object oriented application you could also create a database object with table objects to mirror the structure of the database itself, in this case the database connection would only be active when absolutely necessary - this would generally be much more efficient and easier to use, but much more difficult and time consuming to implement. Several frameworks have classes available to help produce systems like this, though, for example the Zend Framework.

Also keep in mind other methods of storing database connection information - some applications that use multiple databases might store information in XML files to allow greater flexibility in database selection.

There are other ideas around as well, but these are the approaches I've seen used most often.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty much the first thing I do on the page, after setting up some default values (normally using an external config file).

This does mean that every page view will involve a database connection, and that may not be strictly needed, but they more often than not are on the scripts I write.

This way, you know that you are ready to query your database any time you need to.

Comment: Without connection pooling, this could lead to some *major* headaches.